# How to solve the quadratic equation $x^2 - 5x + 6 = 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

How to solve the quadratic equation $x^2 - 5x + 6 = 0 $?

There are two ways to solve it :

a) $x^2 - 3x-2x+6$

$x(x-3) -2(x-3)$

$x=2,3$

b)  $x^2 - 6x+1x+6$

$x(x-6) + 1(x+6) = 0$.

Now , here also I used the same method. But the neither am I able the quadratic equation nor is the method working here.

Also , a quadratic equation cannot have more than $2$ roots. So , either $6$ or $-6$ can’t be the answer. Then , why do I even reach this approach ? Why is it coming different here ?

I think this approach is wrong because :

In this approach , what matters is that in the starting $3 \cdot 2$ ( this $-5x$ which we shortened up into $-3x-2x$) should be equal to $6$, i.e. our constant in the quadratic equation.

Even in 2nd case, $6 \cdot 1 = 6$.

But the problem is the signs: $-3 \cdot -2 = +6$ but not $(-6)(1)=+6$. Therefore , this approach is wrong.

Am I correct?

Comment: You need both factors to be the same so you can pull it out, here you have $x-3$ in both while in the second you have different $x-6,x+6$.

Comment: I think you mean $(-3)(-2) = +6$ instead of $-3-2 = +6$.

Comment: @soupless yes. Multiply

Comment: @Arthur yes. Mistake made in a hurry

Comment: You can further factorise the 1st case $x(x-3)-2(x-3) = (x-2)(x-3)$, then deduce that since the product is $0$, either or both factors are $0$. You can't factorise the 2nd case in the same way.

Comment: @peterwhy Ofc. That’s why I also thought of a reason why. Is that correct do you think ? Because the reason I have given is such a reason with which you won’t have to first solve 2nd case and then check whether  the factors are equal or not.

Comment: why don't you use the third way: [completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) or the [Quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) derived from this  method? This is much simpler.

Comment: @miracle173 Definitely I have done that  but I just also wanted to understand this method. Why ? Every method has a unique approach or derivation.

Comment: @SrijanM.T I would not call this a method because it is necessary to guess a correct solution a (a=2 or a=3), to split -5x to -ax-(5-a)x. it is only a way to show the reader that 2 and 3 are the solutions, but not a way to find the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While splitting the middle term into two terms say $b_1x$ and $b_2x$ the product of their coefficients i.e. $b_1b_2$ should be equal to product of coefficient of $x^2$ say $a$ and constant term, $c$ for factorisation, i.e $b_1b_2=ac$. But here, your $ac=6$ but $b_1b_2= -6$ That's why you are not able to factorise in case b

Comment: Same reason as mine.

Comment: @SrijanM.T Sorry sir, but $a$ need not be equal to $1$ in every quadratic equation. So, your observation that $b_1b_2$ should be equal to just $c$ is flawed.

Comment: Definitely. I’ll change that.

Comment: Is it possible if we can make x-6 equal to x+6 somehow ? So , that we get x+6 in both the brackets for case b.

Comment: @SrijanM.T No, that is not possible, the factorisation of a Quadratic equation into two linear factors is unique (the factors you got in case a are the only factors)

Comment: @SrijanM.T No, $x - 6$ cannot be equal to $x + 6$ because $x - 6 = x + 6$ implies that $-6 = 6$ which is clearly false.

Answer (score 2):

Compare $(a-r_1)(x-r_2) = x^2 - (r_1+r_2)x + r_1r_2$ to $(a-r_1)(x-r_2) = x^2 - 5x + 6$.

$$(x - r_1)(x - r_2) = 
\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
   x^2 & -5x & +6 \\
   x^2 & -(r_1+r_2)x & +r_1r_2
\end{array}\right\}$$

You can see that you need to find $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $r_1+r_2 = 5$ and $r_1 r_2 = 6$

Note that the coefficient of $x^2$ is $1$. When it is not, then you will need to do a bit more work.

There are several ways to do this. The better you are at arithmetic, the easier this will be.

- METHOD $1:$
  Make a list of the pairs of factors that multiply to make $6$.
  \begin{array}{ccc}
     1 & 6 \\ 2 & 3
  \end{array}

Then append a third column that consists of their sums.
\begin{array}{cc|c}
   1 & 6 & 7 \\ 2 & 3 & 5
\end{array}

We see that $r_1=2$ and $r_2=3$ is what we are looking for.

- METHOD $2:$

This method works. But it requires that you be pretty good at arithmetic and at solving simple linear equations.
Let $r_1 = u - v$ and let $r_2 = u+v$

Then $5 = r_1 + r_2 = (u-v) + (u+v) = 2u$. So $u = \dfrac 52$. So

$6 = r_1 r_2 = \left(\dfrac 52 - v\right)\left(\dfrac 52 + v\right)
= \dfrac{25}{4}-v^2$. Solve for $v$.

\begin{align}
   \dfrac{25}{4}-v^2 &= 6 \\
   v_2 - \dfrac{25}{4} &= -6 \\
   4v^2 - 25 &= -24 \\
   4v^2 &= 1 \\
   v^2 &= \dfrac 14 \\
   v &= \dfrac 12
\end{align}

So $r_1 = u - v = \dfrac 52 - \dfrac 12 = 2$

and $r_2 = u + v = \dfrac 52 + \dfrac 12 = 3$

- METHOD $3$: Completing the square.

\begin{align} 
   x^2 - 5x + 6 &= 0 \\
   x^2 - 5x &= -6 
      &\text{Move the constant term over to the other side.} \\
   & & \text{Take half of $5$ and square it. 
             $\left(\dfrac 52 \right)^2 = \dfrac{25}{4}$} \\
  x^2 - 5x + \dfrac{25}{4} &= \dfrac{25}{4} - 6
     &\text{Add that number to both sides.} \\
  \left(x - \frac 52 \right)^2 &= \frac 14 &\text{Simplify} \\
  x - \frac 52 &= \pm \dfrac 12 \\
  x &= \frac 52 \pm \frac 12 \\
  x &= 2, 3
  \end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing. Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The correct factorization of $x^{2} - 5x + 6$ is $(x - 2)(x - 3)$ as shown below.

$$x^{2} - 5x + 6 \\ x^{2} - 2x - 3x + 6 \\ x(x - 2) - 3(x - 2)$$

Now, notice that both $x$ and $-3$ have a common factor which is $x - 2$. Now, by factoring, we have $$(x - 3)(x - 2).$$ You can't do this with the other solution, which is $$x^{2} - 5x + 6 \\ x^{2} - 6x + x + 6 \\ x(x - 6) + (x + 6)$$ because $x - 6 \neq x + 6$.

Comment: . Also because b1b2 is not equal to 6.

Comment: @SrijanM.T That condition $b_1b_2=ac$ is only for the ability to factorise. The actual reason why something can't be factored out in general sense is written in this answer indeed.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha Yes. That’s why I wrote ‘Also’ and gave a  because what soupless has written is right.